# Как сделать правильно списки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет.

Нужно сделать два дива `.list` с двумя колонками списка и что-бы они делили пространство между собой, но возникает одна проблема, когда в первом диве `.list` текста мало во втором списке, то текст улетает далеко, а надо чтобы отступ у неё был как у колонок во втором диве `.list`.

Там из-за текста больше и поэтому список ближе становится относительно первого списка.

Можно ли как-то сделать это?

Хочу сохранить адаптивность не задавая абсолютные величины.

```css
ul li {list-style: none;}

.list {
  max-width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor .<li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor<li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.<li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Lorem .<li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum<li>
  <li>Lorem.<li>
</ul>
</div>


<div class="list">
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Lorem .<li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum<li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet amet<li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: допустим так `.list ul { width: 50%; }` - Величины относительные

Comment: @SwaD спасибо большое) иной раз поражаюсь почему сам не могу додуматься до элементарных ответов )

Comment: Почему вариант с `display: grid` не рассматривался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать размер для тэга

```css
 ul li {
  list-style: none;
 }

 ul {
  width: 300px;
 }

.list {
  max-width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor .<li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor<li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.<li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Lorem .<li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum<li>
  <li>Lorem.<li>
</ul>
</div>


<div class="list">
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Lorem .<li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum<li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet amet<li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Так в вопросе как раз указано, как сделать без абсолютых величин, а у вас как раз абсолютная, да еще и 2 ul превысят максимальную ширину div

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам тоже!

Comment: @SwaD Да, вы всё верно указали. Я использовал ваш вариант т.к нужны относительные величины.